# How to store user selected zoom for future sessions without using cookies Google Geocoder API

Tags: javascript, java, velocity, google-geocoding-api

Using v.3 of the Google geocoder api with a Java back end, Velocity front end and an Oracle db.

Our current spec specifies that when a user selects a marker (lat/lng) that their zoom should be saved as well for future sessions. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I have seen some information about bounds which I think I may be able to use in a hackey way, but I don't want to define the bounds of the map, I just want to save the zoom (like the lat/lng) and be able to pass it to the back end.

### map.js

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var siteLocation;
var marker;

function initMap() {
  var lat = parseFloat($("#newLat").val());
  var lng = parseFloat($("#newLng").val());
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  siteLocation = { lat: lat, lng: lng };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    {
      center: siteLocation,
      zoom: 19,
    }
  );
  //set crosshair
  console.log('setting waypoint marker');
  crosshair = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position: siteLocation,
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      shape: { coords: [0, 0, 0, 0], type: 'rect' },
      icon: "https://www.daftlogic.com/images/cross-hairs.gif"
    }
  );


  crosshair.bindTo('position', map, 'center');
  geocodeLatLng();
}

//use new selection to 
function geocodeLatLng() {
  var lat = crosshair.getPosition().lat();
  var lng = crosshair.getPosition().lng();
  var newLocation = crosshair.getPosition();
  geocoder.geocode({ location : crosshair.position}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

//get new user selected map options, [drop marker] (optional)
$("#addGeolocation").on("click", function (evt) {
  geocodeLatLng();
  evt.preventDefault();
  var newZoom = map.getZoom();
  var newLat = crosshair.getPosition().lat();
  var newLng = crosshair.getPosition().lng();
  $("#newLat").val(newLat);
  $("#newLng").val(newLng);
  newLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng);
  map.setCenter(newLocation);
  map.setZoom(newZoom);
  //make sure no marker exists
  if ( marker !== undefined) {
      marker.setPosition(newLocation);
    } else {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: newLocation,
          map: map,
          draggable: true
      });
    }
});
```

---

**Velocity Macro**

---

```
#macro(map $ADDRESS)
    <script  defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <span class="innerBlock smallBlock" id="map" ></span>
    <button type="button" onclick="geocodeLatLng()" id="addGeolocation"> $BTN_ADD_GEOLOCATION</button>
    #inp_hidden("newLat" "$context.getSite().getLatitude()")
    #inp_hidden("newLng" "$context.getSite().getLongitude()")
    #inp_hidden("newZoom")
#end
```

I am completely stumped. Any ideas? Most of the solutions I have seen involve cookies but we cannot use those. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to store values (localStorage, ajax for backend) .. or how to obtain the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean but correct me if I'm wrong.

You could save the zoom level in a variable.

```
var zoom = 16;
```

and then save this in the local storage

```
localStorage.setItem("zoomLevel", zoom);
```

then use getItem method to retrieve it

```
var savedZoom = localStorage.getItem("zoomLevel");
```

So if you were planning to have the zoom levels in a select box or something, you can save the users choice into the local storage and then retrieve it when they return by setting to zoom to 'savedZoom' for example.

I'm not completely sure if this is what you were after but hopefully it helps. I've tried not to go into too much detail just incase it isn't.

Comment: I actually think it is, I was looking for a workaround but I think this is going to be the most direct way. Thank you! I actually will be using jStorage instead, but should operate the same way